# java urlclassloader that calls a class that has an import dependency

Tags: java, classpath, urlclassloader

After some help in an other thread on urlclassloaders - [understanding urlclassloader, how to access a loaded jar's classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073986/understanding-urlclassloader-how-to-access-a-loaded-jars-classes) 
 I have a follow on question as I don't think I am approaching the problem correctly.

`myPackageA.start` has a urlclassloader calling `myPackageB.comms`
`myPackageB.comms` has an dependency to `import org.jgroups.JChannel` 
form `/home/myJars/jgroups-3.4.2.Final.jar` with the following code

```
    package myPackageB;

    import org.jgroups.JChannel;

    public class SimpleChat {
     JChannel channel;
     String user_name=System.getProperty("user.name", "n/a");

        private void start() throws Exception {
            channel=new JChannel();
            channel.connect("ChatCluster");
            channel.getState(null, 10000);
            channel.close();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new SimpleChat().start();
        }
    }
```

normally I would call the above code with `java -cp /home/myJars/jgroups-3.4.2.Final.jar:myPackageB myPackageB.SimpleChat` and runs as expected.

My question is howit possible to set the -cp within the script so the import works when using the below code to call `myPackageB.SimpleChat` from `java -cp myPackageA.jar myPackageA.start`

```
package myPackageA;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class start 
{
    Class<?> clazz;

    private void start() throws Exception 
    {
        if (this.clazz == null)
            throw new Exception("The class was not loaded properly");

       Object mySc = this.clazz.newInstance(); 
        Method sC = this.clazz.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
        String[] params = null; 
        sC.invoke(mySc,  (Object) params);
    }

    public void loadSc() throws Exception
    {
        URL classUrl;
        classUrl = new URL("file:///home/myJars/myPackageB.jar");
        URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
        Class<?> c = ucl.loadClass("myPackageB.SimpleChat");
        this.clazz = c;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
     {
         start startnow = new start();
         startnow.loadSc();
         startnow.start();
     }
}
```

thanks
Art

Answer (score 0):

Just add the URL for `jgroups-3.4.2.Final.jar` to the `URLClassLoader's` array of URLs.